# IIS 7 returning 400 Bad Request on POST

Tags: iis-7, ajax

Greetings,

i am trying to POST data in a MVC 3 application to a server running IIS 7 using jquery ajax.

When i post normally to the server, everything works ok, just when i post with ajax the server returns a 400 Bad request.

I already ran a trace on such a request but all i got from that was the following:

```
ModuleName="ManagedPipelineHandler",
Notification="EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER",
HttpStatus="400",
HttpReason="Bad Request",
HttpSubStatus="0",
ErrorCode="The operation completed successfully. (0x0)",
ConfigExceptionInfo=""
```

Can anyone point me into the right direction to solve this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this once before.  Wish I could remember the details.  It required a setting change or a hotfix IIRC.

Here's one search result that has a fix although that doesn't ring a bell as the same issue I saw before: http://www.issociate.de/board/post/314237/HTTP_400_Bad_Request.html

Here's another good lead: http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-i-get-http/1-1-400-bad-request-errors.html